# Universal app: Cannot bind `StreamSocketListener` after `EnableTransferOwnership`

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-10, uwp

I am following [this sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SocketActivityStreamSocket) to implement a background server universal app. Here is the experimental code:

```cpp
void MainPage::OnConnectionReceived(StreamSocketListener^ sender, StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs^ args)
{
     OutputDebugString(L"Connection received\n");

     // No idea how to transfer request handling from foreground to background task!
}

void MainPage::OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs^ e)
{
    // Code to register background task is omitted

    auto listener = ref new StreamSocketListener();
    listener->Control->QualityOfService = SocketQualityOfService::Normal;

    try
    {
        listener->EnableTransferOwnership(Task->TaskId, SocketActivityConnectedStandbyAction::Wake);
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        OutputDebugString(L"Error: cannot transfer ownership\n");
    }

    listener->ConnectionReceived += ref new TypedEventHandler<StreamSocketListener^, StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs^>(this, &MainPage::OnConnectionReceived);

    create_task(listener->BindServiceNameAsync("56789", SocketProtectionLevel::PlainSocket))
        .then([this]()
    {
        OutputDebugString(L"Server started on port 56789\n");

        auto m_httpClient = ref new HttpClient();
        auto request = ref new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod::Get, ref new Uri("http://" + ip + ":56789/"));
        auto request_operation = m_httpClient->SendRequestAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption::ResponseContentRead);

        return create_task(request_operation);
    }).then([this](task<HttpResponseMessage^> previousTask)
    {
        try {
            auto response = previousTask.get();
            // Code to process the response is omitted as it is irrelevant to the question
        }
        catch (Exception^ ex)
        {
            OutputDebugString(("Error: " + ex->Message + "\n")->Data());
        }
    });
}
```

At run time, I get the error: **The attempted operation is not supported for the type of object referenced.** which suggests that `BindServiceNameAsync` fails and I have no idea why as I have followed the documentation to do `EnableTransferOwnership` before doing the binding. What did I do wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting **The attempted operation is not supported for the type of object referenced.** because you are using `SocketActivityConnectedStandbyAction::Wake`. Change it to `SocketActivityConnectedStandbyAction::DoNotWake`.

The following pseudo-code should give you an idea what else you need to do to make `StreamSocketListener` working with `SocketActivityTrigger`:

```
// TODO: task = socketTaskBuilder.Register();

socketListener = new StreamSocketListener();

socketListener.ConnectionReceived += OnConnected;

await socketListener.BindServiceNameAsync(port);

socketListener.EnableTransferOwnership(
    task.TaskId,
    SocketActivityConnectedStandbyAction.DoNotWake);

// This is required, otherwise you may get error:
// A device attached to the system is not functioning.
// (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007001F)
await socketListener.CancelIOAsync();

socketListener.TransferOwnership(socketId);
```

Then, in the background task do:

```
public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
{
    var deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();

    var details = taskInstance.TriggerDetails as
        SocketActivityTriggerDetails;

    var socketInformation = details.SocketInformation;
    var streamSocket = socketInformation.StreamSocket;
    var socketListener = socketInformation.StreamSocketListener;

    switch (details.Reason)
    {
        case SocketActivityTriggerReason.ConnectionAccepted:

            // TODO: read, write, etc.

            break;
        default:
            // ...

            break;
    }

    // ...

    deferral.Complete();
}
```

Comment: This works but once in a while, the app cannot be launched and I get **Activation of the app for the Windows.Launch contract failed with error: The remote procedure call failed.** in the event viewer. The only way I know to fix is to ... restart the machine.

Comment: Do you mean the background task does not launch when receiving a connection? Or is it something else?

Comment: Background task does launch; but when resuming, it just never pass the splash screen and the event viewer shows activation error as mentioned. I localize the problem to my attempt to reclaim ownership of the `StreamSocketListener` via `SocketActivityInformation::AllSockets` as instructed in [these slides](http://video.ch9.ms/sessions/build/2015/2-83.Build_2015_FasterMoreCapableCloudApps_v2.pptx). I will prepare the code on GitHub and will update then.

Comment: Here is [my code](https://github.com/anhoavu/BackgroundServer). The [MainPage file](https://github.com/anhoavu/BackgroundServer/blob/master/BackgroundServer/MainPage.xaml.cpp) highlights the various problems that I encountered.